# SQL IF statement Syntax Error: Errors on END in statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm a little rusty on my SQL but trying to make a simple IF statement. I wanted to do IF ELSE but got errors so just trying to do simple comparison now.

code:

```
 --USE [AsurionMobility]
--GO
--/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_RecipientDomain_Report]    Script Date: 8/6/2020 1:15:16 PM ******/
--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO
--SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
--GO

---- =============================================
---- Author:        <Author,,Name>
---- Create date: <Create Date,,>
---- Description:   <Description,,>
---- =============================================
--ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RecipientDomain_Report]
DECLARE
    @startdate smalldatetime = '07-27-2020',
    @enddate smalldatetime = GETDATE(),
    @ClientName AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'Verizon'
--AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @EmailStatus AS TABLE(Domain nvarchar(50), TotalRecords int, TotalBounces int)

    DECLARE @SpecifiedDomains AS TABLE(Domain nvarchar(50), SortOrder int)

    IF @ClientName = 'Verizon' BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @SpecifiedDomains VALUES
        ('AOL.com'          ,10),
        ('Yahoo.com'        ,20),
        ('SBCGlobal.net'    ,30),
        ('Gmail.com'        ,40),
        ('Hotmail.com'      ,50),
        ('Comcast.net'      ,60), 
        ('GE.com'           ,70), 
        ('Verizon.net'      ,80), 
        ('ATT.net'          ,90), 
        ('MSN.com'          ,100),
        ('ATT.com'          ,110),
        ('Misc ISP.'        ,1000)

        ;WITH baseRecords AS 
        (
            SELECT  
                CASE
                    WHEN RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1) - CHARINDEX('@', email1)) IN (SELECT Domain FROM @SpecifiedDomains) 
                    THEN UPPER(RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1) - CHARINDEX('@', email1)))
                    ELSE 'Misc ISP.'
                END AS Domain,
                EmailStatus
            FROM    
                [dbo].[Verizon_Recipients] R
                INNER JOIN DataFile D           
                ON R.OriginalFileID = D.DataFileID
                INNER JOIN EmailPrograms EP
                ON R.EmailProgramID = EP.EmailProgramID
                INNER JOIN Clients C
                ON EP.ClientID = C.ClientID
            WHERE
                D.DataFileDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND
                R.OutputFileID IS NOT NULL AND 
                R.EmailStatus IS NOT NULL AND 
                C.ClientName = @ClientName
        )
    END 
    
    IF @ClientName = 'AT&T' BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @SpecifiedDomains VALUES
        ('AOL.com'          ,10),
        ('Yahoo.com'        ,20),
        ('SBCGlobal.net'    ,30),
        ('Gmail.com'        ,40),
        ('Hotmail.com'      ,50),
        ('Comcast.net'      ,60), 
        ('GE.com'           ,70), 
        ('Verizon.net'      ,80), 
        ('ATT.net'          ,90), 
        ('MSN.com'          ,100),
        ('ATT.com'          ,110),
        ('Misc ISP.'        ,1000)

        ;WITH baseRecords AS 
        (
            SELECT  
                CASE
                    WHEN RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1) - CHARINDEX('@', email1)) IN (SELECT Domain FROM @SpecifiedDomains) 
                    THEN UPPER(RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1) - CHARINDEX('@', email1)))
                    ELSE 'Misc ISP.'
                END AS Domain,
                EmailStatus
            FROM    
                [dbo].[ATT_Recipients] R
                INNER JOIN DataFile D           
                ON R.OriginalFileID = D.DataFileID
                INNER JOIN EmailPrograms EP
                ON R.EmailProgramID = EP.EmailProgramID
                INNER JOIN Clients C
                ON EP.ClientID = C.ClientID
            WHERE
                D.DataFileDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND
                R.OutputFileID IS NOT NULL AND 
                R.EmailStatus IS NOT NULL AND 
                C.ClientName = @ClientName
        )
    END 

    IF @ClientName <> 'AT&T' AND @ClientName <> 'Verizon' BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @SpecifiedDomains VALUES
        ('AOL.com'          ,10),
        ('Yahoo.com'        ,20),
        ('SBCGlobal.net'    ,30),
        ('Gmail.com'        ,40),
        ('Hotmail.com'      ,50),
        ('Comcast.net'      ,60), 
        ('GE.com'           ,70), 
        ('Verizon.net'      ,80), 
        ('ATT.net'          ,90), 
        ('MSN.com'          ,100),
        ('ATT.com'          ,110),
        ('Misc ISP.'        ,1000)

        ;WITH baseRecords AS 
        (
            SELECT  
                CASE
                    WHEN RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1) - CHARINDEX('@', email1)) IN (SELECT Domain FROM @SpecifiedDomains) 
                    THEN UPPER(RIGHT(Email1, LEN(Email1) - CHARINDEX('@', email1)))
                    ELSE 'Misc ISP.'
                END AS Domain,
                EmailStatus
            FROM    
                [dbo].[Recipients] R
                INNER JOIN DataFile D           
                ON R.OriginalFileID = D.DataFileID
                INNER JOIN EmailPrograms EP
                ON R.EmailProgramID = EP.EmailProgramID
                INNER JOIN Clients C
                ON EP.ClientID = C.ClientID
            WHERE
                D.DataFileDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND
                R.OutputFileID IS NOT NULL AND 
                R.EmailStatus IS NOT NULL AND 
                C.ClientName = @ClientName
        )
    END
```

It gives me a error on the "End" on all the statements. I read some posts that suggest I need to use a SELECT statement? I tried using a SELECT but still got syntax errors. Sorry been awhile since I made SQL IF statement. I'm not sure if dynamic SQL would be best option?

Comment: Common table expressions must come before the query they relate to. You cannot insert arbitrary control flow statements in and around them

Comment: You declare a CTE (for example `baseRecords), but there's no `SELECT` for it. you have unended statements.

Comment: Side note, `;` is a statement **terminator**, it goes at the *end* of **all** your statements. It's not a "beginningator" that goes at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Comment: @Larnu - I know you're funning but the opposite of terminator would probably be initiator.

Comment: The term isn't mine, @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it's something that someone else coined a long time ago in a different community, and it's stuck with me and other in the community since then. But I wasn't "funning", my point was serious. `;` doesn't go at the beginning of a statement, it goes at the end. That's why it's called a statement **terminator**; it terminates the statement, not begins (or as you say, initiates) it.

Answer (score -2):

As pointed out by [damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) and [larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu), you have to fix your CTE first like the following query.

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)  
AS  
-- Define the CTE query.  
(  
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear  
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL  
)  
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.  
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear  
FROM Sales_CTE  
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID  
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, SalesYear;
```

For more info on the syntax of CTE, please visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) from microsoft.